# Scala Redis Driver - usng blpop command

Tags: scala, redis

I'm trying to use blpop Redis command which will return some Long value after 10 seconds tieout:

```
 val r = new RedisClient("10.0.0.15", 6379)

    implicit val parseV =  new com.redis.serialization.Parse[Long](f=>{ByteBuffer.wrap(f).getLong})
    val rs =  r.blpop[String,Long](10,"queue")
    rs match{
        case Some(s)=>println(s._2)
        case None => println("timeOut");
    }
```

However on time out I'm getting the exception below,

The interesting thing is that if the returned Object would be long the size if byte[] should be 8 bytes( length of long is 64 bit in Java), but in case if exception the returned byte[] has 5 bytes length.

What it is? 
How should I take care or prevent this exception?
This is the StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextGetIndex(Buffer.java:498)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getLong(HeapByteBuffer.java:406)
    at com.vanilla.scala.redis.ScalaRedis$$anonfun$1.apply(ScalaRedis.scala:14)
    at com.vanilla.scala.redis.ScalaRedis$$anonfun$1.apply(ScalaRedis.scala:13)
    at com.redis.serialization.Parse.apply(Serialization.scala:54)
    at com.redis.serialization.Parse.apply(Serialization.scala:53)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at com.redis.R$class.asBulk(RedisProtocol.scala:121)
    at com.redis.RedisClient.asBulk(RedisClient.scala:60)
    at com.redis.StringOperations$$anonfun$get$1.apply(StringOperations.scala:26)
    at com.redis.StringOperations$$anonfun$get$1.apply(StringOperations.scala:26)
    at com.redis.Redis$class.send(RedisClient.scala:21)
    at com.redis.RedisClient.send(RedisClient.scala:60)
    at com.redis.StringOperations$class.get(StringOperations.scala:26)
    at com.redis.RedisClient.get(RedisClient.scala:60)
    at com.vanilla.scala.redis.ScalaRedis$delayedInit$body.apply(ScalaRedis.scala:23)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:40)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:71)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:32)
    at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:71)
    at com.vanilla.scala.redis.ScalaRedis$.main(ScalaRedis.scala:7)
    at com.vanilla.scala.redis.ScalaRedis.main(ScalaRedis.scala)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting this exception because the value returned from redis is actually a String representation of the Long value.

Take a look at the [Implicit Parser](https://github.com/debasishg/scala-redis/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/redis/Serialization.scala#L39) that RedisClient provides for and you'll see that it first constructs a String (from UTF-8 encoded bytes) and then calls toLong() on it.

This also means that you can use this Parser instead of defining your own:

```
val r = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379)

implicit val parseV = com.redis.serialization.Parse.Implicits.parseLong
val rs =  r.blpop[String,Long](10,"queue")
rs match{
    case Some(s)=>println(s._2)
    case None => println("timeOut");
}
```